# Mongoose aggregation: Query within "group" phase

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

I have the following problem:

I have the following two models:

```
Assignment: {
  _id,
  isPublic: Boolean
}

Solution: {
  _id,
  totalTime: Number,
  assignment: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Assignment' },

}
```

and I want to query all solutions, group them by assignment, but I only care for assignments that are public (isPublic === true).

But I have no idea where to make that query. Can you help me?

My aggregation so far looks like this:

```
{
        $match: {
            assignment: {
                $exists: true,
                $ne: null,
            },
        },
        {
            $group: {
                _id: '$assignment',
                totalTime: { $sum: '$totalTime' },
            },
        },
        {
            $sort: {
                totalTime: -1,
            },
        }
}
```

This works fine, but how can I filter my results to only consider public assignments? All filter and query methods I found only seem to work within `find()`, but not for an aggregation.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$lookup` with pipeline,

- `$lookup` to join `Assignment` collection
- `$match` assignment id and is public true
- `$match` outside lookup, check is assignment not empty [],

```
  { $match: ...  }, // skipping 

  // add this
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "Assignment",
      let: { aId: "$assignment" },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: { $eq: ["$_id", "$$aId"] },
            isPublic: true
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "assignments"
    }
  },
  // add this
  { $match: { assignments: { $ne: [] } } },

  { $group: ... }, // skipping
  { $sort: ... } // skipping
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/h11h_vlVBQW)